# I can't find the error in a tikzcd diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

The code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    \hom(A, A) \arrow[d, "\hom(A, f)"] \arrow[r, "\hom(h, B)"] & \hom(A', B) \arrow[d, "\hom(A', f)"] \\
    \hom(A, B') \arrow[r, "\hom(h, B')"] & \hom(A', B')
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

and it gives a lot of errors, the first one being

Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/f)"' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try adding braces, e.g. `"{\hom(A, f)}"`.

Comment: I confirm that @marmot suggestion solves the problem. **But** insert braces in all arrow labels.

Comment: @marmot Thanks, that fixed it! So why is that necessary here? In the other diagrams I've made it was not, even if I used \times or something like that.

Comment: Also, you could want to use `\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2cm]` to change the columns space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem  comes from the commas inside `\hom`, which interfere with the commas separating the arguments of `\arrow` . Just add a pair of braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=huge]%[column sep=3em]
    \hom(A, A) \arrow[d, "{\hom(A, f)}"] \arrow[r, "{\hom(h, B)}"] & \hom(A', B) \arrow[d, "{\hom(A', f)}"] \\%
    \hom(A, B') \arrow[r, "{\hom(h, B')}"] & \hom(A', B')%
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]